# How to get paste to work for pasting in text in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to limit the number of characters to 70 per line and only allow 10 lines in a multi line textbox. It works fine.

But when I want to paste some text into the textbox...nothing appears in the textbox.
How do I get paste to work in a textbox also?

```
Private Sub TextBox24_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox24.TextChanged

    Static txtPrev As String
    Dim MaxCharsPerLine As Integer = 70

    If TextBox24.Lines.GetUpperBound(0) >= 10 Then
        TextBox24.Text = txtPrev
        TextBox24.SelectionStart = TextBox24.Text.Length
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox24.Lines.GetUpperBound(0)
            If TextBox24.Lines(i).Length > MaxCharsPerLine Then
                TextBox24.Text = txtPrev
                TextBox24.SelectionStart = TextBox24.Text.Length
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        txtPrev = TextBox24.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

I really didn't find anything related to this issue online.

Comment: Why are you making it so hard on yourself? Why do you care how many characters per line at all? If you just turn wordwrap on and limit it to a max of 70 characters overall, it makes it much easier on both you and your users. Also, please do not invent your own code formatting here - use the built-in formatting for code. You can find help on using it by clicking the **?** button on the right side of the toolbar when writing or editing your post. And you'll find your experiences here much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and reading the [help] pages before you begin posting.

Comment: Also, my point about making it too hard is just this: the multi-line edit can have a max text length assigned, which means you don't have to do anything at all except tell it to only allow 70 characters. This means that your entire code can be deleted, and copy/paste will work just like it does everywhere else in Windows.